# Canada: New mortgage qualification rules, 2010: Why, what, & when in effect?

Tags: canada, mortgage, mortgage-qualification, real-estate

Earlier today, the Canadian federal Finance Minister Jim Flaherty announced new mortgage qualification rules for Canada.

- Why were new rules introduced?
- What are the new rules being introduced, vs. what they were before?
- When will the new rules take effect?
- Where is definitive information about the new rules available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The new mortgage qualification rules were introduced to cool a hot Canadian housing real estate market.** The rules are a pre-emptive measure intended to avoid a bubble (and later crash) in real estate. The government wants to make sure anybody buying a house can handle higher interest rates. Those rates, currently at record lows, are expected to go up later this year and into the future.

The tighter mortgage rules include:

- Borrowers will need to qualify against a minimum standard **5-year fixed rate mortgage**, even if they'll contract their mortgage at a lower or variable rate.  Previously, the **3-year fixed rate mortgage** was used as the minimum qualification standard.
- The amount a homeowner can borrow in a refinanced mortgage drops to **90% of the home value**, down from **95% of the home value.**  A home is not meant to be an ATM machine.
- Anybody wanting to borrow to buy an **investment property** – i.e. a property that won't be their *principal residence* – will need a **20% downpayment** instead of a **5% downpayment.**

The new rules go into effect **April 19th, 2010.**  However, according to the backgrounder (see below):

> Exceptions would be allowed after
>   April 19 where they are needed to
>   satisfy a binding purchase and sale,
>   financing, or refinancing agreement
>   entered into before April 19, 2010.

**Definitive information** about the new rules can be found at the **[Department of Finance of Canada](http://www.fin.gc.ca/fin-eng.asp)**.  Specifically, refer to:

- [the news release from the Department of Finance](http://www.fin.gc.ca/n10/10-011-eng.asp).
- and [the backgrounder for that news release](http://www.fin.gc.ca/n10/data/10-011%5F1-eng.asp).

Some additional news media sources:

- [CBC News - Money - Flaherty tightens mortgage taps](http://www.cbc.ca/money/story/2010/02/16/mortgage-flaherty.html)
- [National Post - Ottawa to toughen mortgage rules](http://www.nationalpost.com/news/story.html?id=2570414)

Comment: Was there not a provision altering the maximum amortization period? I recall discussions about the "new normal" of 35 year terms, and the desire to bring that back to a maximum of 25 years.

Comment: As far as I know, there was no such provision in the April 2010 announcement to eliminate the 35-year amortization period.  However, *40-year* mortgages came to an end in October, 2008.  Refer to http://www.cbc.ca/consumer/story/2008/10/15/40-year.html .. Perhaps the Department of Finance talked of doing more in April 2010, but relented?  I don't know.

Comment: What is a principal residence? If one buys a second home and divides his time between the 2 homes, which is the principal residence here?

Comment: @Kaushik If you own two homes and "ordinarily inhabit" each, then you can, for tax purposes, choose to designate only **one** of the two as your principal residence.

Comment: Thanks Chris. But on the new one, do I put 20% down...if the question of which one is principal residence is unclear....

Comment: @Kaushik You'll have to ask the bank.