# What impact does the new mortgage rules have on CMHC policies? [Canada]

Tags: canada, mortgage, mortgage-qualification, real-estate

With reference to this [question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/canada-new-mortgage-qualification-rules-2010-why-what-when-in-effect), how does this affect the Canadian Home and Mortgage Corporation (CMHC)?  This organization made it possible to get a new home with as little as 5% downpayment, essentially insuring the borrower in case of default.  Will this change with the new rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Banks will still require CMHC insurance on loans that exceed a certain amount of the property's value (currently 80%). However, the new rules will mean that even if you get CMHC, you must put down at least 10% for a principal residence, and 20% for a rental property.
The qualification rule change doesn't really have anything to do with CMHC, it's just a new standard for how the banks calculate your [debt-to-income ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debt-to-income_ratio).

Comment: Would first-time buyers still be able to put 5% down?

Comment: Yes, I believe the 5% still applies to first time home buyers.